# CSS Media Queries not working as intended

Tags: css

Second media querie works fine - **(min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 992px)** - but the first on just does not work - **(max-width: 600px)**.

Am i missing something? Cause even if i add **min-width** to first one it still does not work.

```
.center {
 font-size:70px;
 color:white;
 position: absolute;
 height: 50px;
 top: 40%;
 left: 30%;
 margin-left: -50px; /* margin is -0.5 * dimension */
 margin-top: -25px; 
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Josefin Sans";
 font-weight: bold;
}​

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
body {
   background-color: olive;

 }
.center{
  margin-left:-135px;
  font-size:60px;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 992px){
body {
   background-color: blue;
 }
}
```

Comment: It works for me. However, what background color should it have if it's above 992px?

Comment: What is happening in your browser if you resize?

Comment: try `@media  screen and (max-width: 600px)` without `only`

Comment: @Naomi Im using background-url above. When u resize my browser only the second media statement works.

Comment: @AkashPinnaka Only second media statement works.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/aVylBP Added full code of my project.

Comment: @Krizs see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some dot in your code **remove it** (see image)
`Here is working one:`https://jsfiddle.net/tben7qz8/4/ 
You can try `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)` without `only`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was a hidden symbol behind the brackets. Noticed that when i posted the code.